# Reading full screen on a mac

Tags: macos, fullscreen

On Windows, if I want to enjoy a rtf book, I use MS word and use the full screen reading view.

What is a similar/inexpensive solution on the mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Preview` has a very nice full screen mode enabled by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

You will have to resave the rtf document as a PDF using TextEdit.

Comment: Cmd-F is find? Did you mean Slideshow mode using Cmd-Shift-F?

Comment: On Snow Leopard its Cmd-Shift-F. Also you won't be able to open an .rtf with Preview but you can open the .rtf with TextEdit and Save As PDF.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't click anywhere to go to the next page, only on a relatively small button. :(

Comment: @Charles: You can press the left and right arrow keys to move pages.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the [megazoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/) plugin, which allows any cocoa application to become full screen. Every time I used it on a terminal window I feel nostalgic of DOS days...

Answer (score 0):

MS Word is available on OSX as well, so you can simply keep using that if you wish.

Comment: Geh, I bought MS Office 2008... it does not have this feature?!

Comment: @Charles: I'm sure it does...